# How to copy all files by specified extension to another location recursively

Tags: powershell

I was trying the accepted solution here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/194827/writing-a-powershell-script-to-copy-files-with-certain-extension-from-one-folder/223014#223014
But it doesnt work, and my comment on the accepted solution is not getting a response.

I am trying to copy all pictures I have in my Pictures drive (only PNG, JPG, without the video files) to a different drive, but having no luck.

Ideally I want to copy recursively, but to a flat destination (not mirroring the source sub-directories)

I tried this command:
`Copy-Item -path "C:\Users\genadi\Pictures\" -include "*.JPG", "*.PNG"  -Destination "D:\"` with and without `-recurse` but nothing happens.

Ideally, I want a script that will 1) reduce original size of all JPG and PNG pictures (including all sub-folders) and 2) copy the reduced size to specified destination.

Currently my originals are about 20GB, I need to fit them on a flash drive for display/printing purposes etc. and easily repeat this when needed (hence why script would be nice).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's because the object name returned by the cmdlet doesn't include the extension, you need to append `\*`. I'm not sure if `Copy-Item` allows you to "collapse" the destination directory, so I would use `Get-ChildItem` with `-Recurse` and pipe it to `Copy-Item`

```cs
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\genadi\Pictures\*" -Include *.jpg,*.png -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination D:\
```